# Which regression type should i use?

Tags: regression

I want to use logistic regression on spss to examine the factors associated with bottled water use.
A survey was distributed with these questions:

1.enter your gender (m, f), faculty (8 faculties to choose from), academic year (5 options)
 2.your poinion (yes or no):
- do you think bottled water is cleaner than tap water
- do you think bottled water is safer than tap water
- do you think bottled water is tastier than tap water
- do you think bottled water has an impact on human
- do you think bottled water has an impact on the environment

Can someone show me the steps to get these outcome: the adjusted odd ratio, confidence interval and p-value.

I really appreciate your help. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your hands looks like a classification problem rather than a regression one. Fortunatelly, you already know a classification technique (confusingly enough: logistic regression)

You may also want to tree different classifiers such as decision trees, which work great with categorical data